# My question was closed as off-topic; is there a way I could restructure it to be relevant? Or another SE site I could use?

Tags: support

My question was about the best strategy to solve a technical problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526173/whats-the-best-way-to-stay-logged-in-to-atlassian-sites-like-jira-fisheye-cru

It was closed as off-topic because the answer is subjective:  I was looking for suggestions, and as such, there is no one "right" answer. However, I feel that the question has merits:

- I think there *is* a solution out there that will solve my problem
- It's probably solvable by creating a Google Chrome Extension
- I'd wager that it's a common problem, and other people will likely benefit from the solution

So that being said, is there a StackExchange site that I could move my question to, where it would *not* be off-topic? (e.g. SuperUser or WebApps) Or, failing that, is there a way I could rephrase it so that it's on-topic?

I could have been more specific; e.g. I could have asked how website login timeouts work, or how to GET/POST to a site in the background on an automated interval via a GCE. But I didn't want to limit the solution by assuming this was the best path to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance for your feedback; some times knowing how to ask the right question is 50% of the problem.

Comment: As a result of the meta discussion, I've [migrated the post over to Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/396333/whats-the-best-way-to-stay-logged-in-to-atlassian-sites-like-jira-fisheye-cru)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's off-topic for Stack Overflow, since it's not a programming problem you're trying to solve.

It might be on-topic for [Super User](http://superuser.com) as you're specifically asking about the Chrome browsers.

It's probably better on [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), though. You are asking about staying logged in to different web apps, after all.

I'd caution you about using "what's the best" type language. It smacks of subjective language. Better to ask "how" to do something; people will already give you what *they* think is the best solution.

Comment: It's not on topic for Web Apps. These are no public webapps, but personally hosted scripts. At least I guess it would be okay for SU.

Comment: OK, is there a way to "move" my question over Super User? Or do I just copy and paste, with some tweaks to my wording (so it doesn't sound so subjective)?

Comment: @SteveK - questions can (and are) migrated. If you want it moved sooner flag it for moderator attention.